# prove or disprove:if $A$ is a real skew symmetric matrix and $I+A$ is nonsingular then $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

can anyone show me how to prove or disprove this question coz I'm having hard time trying to understand how to do it.do I have to use eigenvalues or can it be solve just by using the properties of skew-symmetric matrix and nonsingular matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Let's verify it:

$$\left((I-A)(I+A)^{-1}\right)^T(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}=\left((I+A)^{-1}\right)^T(I-A)^T(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}\\=\left((I+A)^{-1}\right)^T(I+A)(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}=\left((I+A)^{-1}\right)^T(I-A)\underbrace{(I+A)(I+A)^{-1}}_{=I}\\=(I-A)^{-1}(I-A)=I$$
so the answer is YES this matrix is orthogonal.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ^_^
now I can clearly see what to do,my mind totally went blank after several questions..huhu
cc: @SamiBenRomdhane

Comment: You're welcome.